# Snapshot's srcs are not updated by Idea

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, sbt

I publish snapshot artifact to oss in order to use it in another project.
It has version 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.

When i change some code in that snapshot version i use command **update** to fetche changes. Sbt detects these changes but Intellij Idea shows old changes.

Idea shows jars folder correctly but id doesn't contain source code.

I found a solution: I deleted that snapshot artifact from ~/.ivy/myartifact and after update idea works fine. But it's too long, need another solution

Comment: are the changes not updated in IDEA after running `update` and refreshing the sbt project in IDEA?

Comment: I've solved this issue. I've used nexus server in order to cache artifacts from different servers. Now i'm not using any proxy servers and it works just fine...